# How can I automatically upload code changes on a remote VM

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, sync, sftp

My current works involves working on scripts running on a Ubuntu VM.

For multiple reasons, I'm editing and committing project files on a local computer running Windows, and running them on a remote server through a SSH connection (using MobaXTerm). My build process when developing is roughly as follows:

- Write the changes in my local text editor.
- Open the right directory in MobaXTerm's SFTP UI.
- Click "Upload file", and select the right directory and file in the Windows file browser.
- Run `systemctl restart apache2.service` or whatever I need on the VM.

(obviously the build process for production builds is much more thorough and automatized)

Steps 2 and 3 feel pretty redundant. They're repetitive, easy to forget, easy to get wrong, and I'm generally giving the computer information it should know better than me.

**Is there a standardized, safe way to automatically synchronize a local folder with a remote SSH folder from Windows?**

Essentially, what I want is some utility that goes *File `myDirectory/foo/bar/X` has changed! Uploading file X to `someUrl/theirDirectory/foo/bar/X`* with minimum configuring.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "standardized way".

You have these options:

- Use a tool that can watch for changes in a local directory and reflect them on a remote SFTP directory.
- Schedule a frequent synchronization of a local folder against a remote folder.
- There are (commercial) tools that can map a remote SFTP folder to a local drive. Using these you can directly work with/edit remote files using any local application.
- Some editors allow direct editing of files on an SFTP server.

---

You can implement the first two options with [WinSCP SFTP client](https://winscp.net/).

---

### Watching for changes

Use ["Keep remote directory up to date" function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date) of WinSCP.

It can be used both in command-line/console mode using the [`keepuptodate` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_keepuptodate), like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=c:\writable\path\to\synchronize.log /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

Or in a [graphical/GUI mode](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_keepuptodate). You can launch the graphical mode in WinSCP GUI (after logging in) or from a command-line using the [`/keepuptodate` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#operations) like:

```
winscp.exe sftp://username:password@example.com/ /keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path
```

---

### Scheduling

To synchronize changes in a local directory to a remote directory, use the WinSCP [`synchronize` script command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize) from a batch file like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=c:\writable\path\to\synchronize.log /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
    "synchronize remote C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
    "exit"
```

And [schedule the batch file to be run frequently using Windows scheduler](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

For details see also a guide to [automating file transfers (or synchronization) to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*