# How to set up "keep remote up to date" as a default?

Tags: winscp

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_keep_up_to_date discusses "keep remote directory up to date."

But it says "This will not save transfer settings. You can change default transfer settings in preferences. Note that defaults affect function Synchronize as well.'

Thus I would like to understand how to save "keep remote directory up to date" setting so that it will update the remote wheneverI start Winscp without going through the setup each time.

*Follow-up: the command line option is

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /log=c:\writable\path\to\synchronize.log /command ^
"open sftp://username:password@example.com/" ^
"keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path" ^
"exit"
```

Would you explain this command line option in more details? How does it work for private key/public key authentication for

```
//username:password@example.com/"
```

?

*Follow-up2: I can make things work with GUI. But in Win10 shortcut, when I type

```
 winscp.exe session -keepuptodate Ctest -home2-(my username)
```

It says "the shortcut name you entered either contained characters that are invalid for file names or was too long." What is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start "Keep remote directory up to date" automatically, you can use the [`/keepuptodate` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#operations):

```
winscp.exe session /keepuptodate C:\local\path /remote/path
```

You can create a desktop shortcut that will execute a command line the one above.

A related question: [How can I automatically upload code changes on a remote VM](https://superuser.com/q/1385879/213663)