# Automatic File Sync in WinSCP

Tags: debian, sync, automation, sftp, winscp

I saw a few articles and videos on how to write a script to sync a remote and local directory, whether that be remote-local, local-remote or bidirectional. However that script has to be run by the user, and I don't see the point in double-clicking my so-said automatic sync script every time I want to update my directory(s) rather than just hitting "synchronise" in the WinSCP GUI.

Is there a way to make WinSCP update the directories every time a file changes? Just to make sure I'm clear, I'm not interested in it synchronising on *startup*, but rather every time a file changes.

By the way, I'm running WinSCP on Debian, using Wine, but I don't think that matters much.

Comment: Call me old fashioned.. but running WinSCP under Wine on Debian seems downright crazy to me.  WinSCP emulates linux functionality which you are emulating on linux?  (wine IS an emulator, wine is not a VM didnt make a catchy acronym). First of all, you don't want all of those cycles used up CONSTANTLY watching for file changes but I understand that you don't want to kick it off by hand.  I myself would use `cron` and the `rsync` utility to accomplish this the unix way.  Google will take you right to places that will tell you how to pull this off.

Comment: See [How can I automatically upload code changes on a remote VM](https://superuser.com/q/1385879/213663) or [Keep FTP folder synchronized with Windows folder](https://superuser.com/q/48782/213663).

Comment: @Señor CMasMas That sounds great, and I'd rather just call it simple and smart than old-fashioned but, according to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp), `rsync` doesn't work over FTP, which is what I need. I'll try with `lftp` instead. Thank you for knocking me out of my stupidity.

Comment: :D  You can actually mount FTP sites in linux and use rsync against them as if any other file system (samba too!).