# How to open a remote SSH MobaXterm folder with VSCode

Tags: windows, remote, visual-studio-code, mobaxterm, files-folders

With MobaXterm on Windows, I am able to open a SSH remote file with `VSCode` just by double clicking it (after that I set this is my default text editor). However, I am not able to open a folder and all it subfiles with vscode.

The following screenshot shows that I can open the folder Badminton with VSCode as it is in local in my computer.

[image]

This next screenshot shows that I can't open folder `OBSC - SingleBattery` with `VSCode` which is a remote folder on a SSH session in MobaXterm.

[image]

When I double click `OBSC - SingleBattery`, it enters inside it within MobaXterm (which is the most convenient behavior for a folder). Right+click doesn't allow you to `open the folder with`, oppositely to files. I also tried to open the folder within vscode with the corresponding path:

```
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm\slash\RemoteFiles\67288_7_20\Project.toml (One of the files within my folder that'd like to open with VSCode)
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\MobaXterm\slash\RemoteFiles\67288_7_20 (path that I open with vscode)
```

But that only opens one folder with one file (for this instance `Project.toml`) instead of all the files inside the folder.

Using MobaXterm is mandatory. Using VSCode is not, I am open to Atom as well or any editor that you would suggest that can handle this functionality and is convenient for developing JuliaLang projects.

EDIT thanks to @harrymc comments and answer
My SSH settings in MobaXterm are:

```
RemoteHost: bastion1.SomeURL.fr
Specified Username: julien@p-convince.rd.SomeURL.fr:DGSN8662@ad.SomeURL.fr
Port: 22
```

Comment: Is the procedure described the article [Connect over SSH with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial) a solution? It uses the [Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh).

Comment: When you open a file by double-clicking it in MobaXterm, it copies that one file over to your local machine's appdata folder first, then opens that local file in your editor. Editors like vscode have no knowledge of how to find other files that don't exist on your local machine yet. Some other ssh clients like winscp have better features to sync remote and local files, like: https://superuser.com/a/1385889/673426

Comment: @harrymc, I edited my question thanks to your comments and answer

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the procedure described the article
[Connect over SSH with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial).

The article uses the
[Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh):

> **Remote - SSH**
>
> With the Remote - SSH extension installed, you will see a new Status
> bar item at the far left.
>
> [image]
>
> The Remote Status bar item can quickly show you in which context VS
> Code is running (local or remote) and clicking on the item will bring
> up the Remote - SSH commands.
>
> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I installed the extension. My remote host is: `bastion1.someURL.fr` my port is 22 and my specified ssh username is: `julien@p-convince.rd.someURL.fr:SomeNickname@someURL.fr`. How would I specify that on the Remote-SSH configuration file? `SomeURL` is the same for the three occurences.

Comment: I don't have your environment for testing, but the article seems very detailed.